# About 게 and 거예요

Tags: grammar

I know that when 게 is used in a sentence, it means the speaker is somehow being affected and then decides what is going to do. But how about when 게 is used in a question. What is the difference between these two sentences?

내일 뭐 할게요?

내일 뭐 할거예요?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have completely different constructions and meanings, and the former one (“내일 뭐 할게요?”) is unusual.

---

##### 내일 뭐 할<sub>(“하-”<sub>verb stem “do”</sub>＋“-ㄹ”<sub>modifier</sub>)</sub> 거예요<sub>(“거”<sub>nominal marker “to”</sub>＋“이-”<sub>copula “be”</sub>＋“-에요”<sub>honorific ending</sub>)</sub>?

“**내일 뭐 할 거예요?**” is an ordinary question. “**What are (you) doing tomorrow?**”

##### 내일 뭐 할게요<sub>(“하-”<sub>verb stem “do”</sub>＋“-ㄹ게”<sub>ending with willingness</sub>＋“요”<sub>honorific postposition</sub>)</sub>?

“**내일 뭐 할게요?**” is not. It’s not what you’d see or hear often that some might find it even wrong. It is the question mark that makes it unusual *because the sentence itself is not a question*. Without any contexts given, it sounds to me as if the speaker’s telling the listener “**(우리) 내일 뭐 할게요.**” (“**(We’re) going to do something tomorrow.**”; with an *implied subject* “we.”) with a questioning tone at the end to make sure the listener is paying attention; that is, a sentence with a tag question implied. “**(We’re) doing something tomorrow, (okay/got it)?**”